# Is it possible to fast forward simulation in Box2D

Tags: box2d, simulation

I create a box2d world, put some objects on the screen with different properties like rotation, restitution ,density. And then I start the application. Is it possible to fast forward the simulation so that I can see the result quickly? By result I mean the final state of the world objects. Just like a video clip.

Comment: run Step function multiple times. But it costs

Comment: Great, thanks Andrew. That does just what I need. I need this for debugging purposes anyway.

Comment: @MikeJM, you should post the solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: @JSuar, to be polite I was waiting for Andrew to post it as it was his idea to run Step multiple times.

Comment: @MikeJM, yea, I hear ya. I was thinking he might not since it was just a suggestion/comment. Either way, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Andrew I found that if I run the Step function multiple times, I can get the fast forwarded simulation. Here's just a little code that I guess anybody could write:

```
-(void)simulateWithFastForwardRate:(int)ffRate timeStep:(float32)timeStep
                    velocity:(int)velIters 
       andPositionIterations:(int)posIters{
     for(int i=0;i<ffRate;i++){
       _world->Step(timeStep,velIters,posIters);
     }
}
```

Just run the above method passing it the fast forward rate, velocity and position iterations.