# How can I implement "time compression" in box2d physics engine?

Tags: time, box2d, andengine, physics-engine

I am implementing a game in Andengine using physics. The physics looks quite real, but the game feels slow and boring. Is there any way to change the physics engine timing in case I want to implement some time compression, like fast forward, or slow motion?

The only way I figured to do it is overriding the onUpdate method of PhysicsWorld and multiplying elapsed seconds by a factor, but Im afraid of being spoiling some internal calculation of the engine.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
    super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed * mTimeCompression);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(This should probably be a comment but I don't have enough rep yet.)

I think that your suspicion about spoiling the internal calculations is correct -  see: https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/

A similar question was asked and the solution involves calling `step` (which seems to be `onUpdate` in your case) multiple times rather than changing the time step itself: [Is it possible to fast forward simulation in Box2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208549/is-it-possible-to-fast-forward-simulation-in-box2d?answertab=active#tab-top)